# Can a function be one of kwargs in Python partial?

Tags: python, functional-programming, partial

I would like to use `functools.partial` to reduce the number of arguments in one of my functions. Here's the catch: one or more `kwargs` may be functions themselves. Here's what I mean:

```
from functools import partial

def B(alpha, x, y):
    return alpha(x)*y

def alpha(x):
    return x+1

g = partial(B, alpha=alpha, y=2)
print(g(5))
```

This throws an error:

> TypeError: B() got multiple values for argument 'alpha'

Can `partial` handle functions as provided arguments? If not is there a workaround or something more generic than `partial`?

Comment: Python functions are objects like any other. Your issue is only with passing `alpha` as a kwarg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`partial` itself doesn't know that a given positional argument should be assigned to `x` just because you specified a keyword argument for `alpha`. If you want `alpha` to be particular function, pass that function as a positional argument to `partial`.

```
>>> g = partial(B, alpha, y=2)
>>> g(5)
12
```

`g` is equivalent to

```
def g(x):
    return alpha(x) * 2  #  == (x + 1) * 2
```

---

Alternately, you can use your original definition of `g`, but be sure to pass `5` as a keyword argument as well, avoiding any additional positional arguments.

```
>>> g = partial(B, alpha=alpha, y=2)
>>> g(x=5)
12
```

This works because between `g` and `partial`, you have provided keyword arguments for all required parameters, eliminating the need for any positional arguments.